# Store last played songs Android media player app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I'm currently developing a media player application for Android. Now, I would like to store the last played songs. Which approach for persistence should I take to do this ? I mean, should I use SharedPreferences, o perhaps SQLLite database, or something else ?

I would settle for save the songs ID in some specific order. It's not necessary to save the title, artist or album of the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have seen all the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) that android provides. If you read the `SharedPreference` part, `it provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types`. It also supports saving `sets` and `ArrayList`. See [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) questions. If you just want to store the last played song ID's, then using `SharedPreference` might be preferable. It is also faster than using database.

However, if you have more structured data, then using database might be better to manage. To know more about when `SharedPreference` would be good to use and when `SQL Lite` database, read [Pros and Cons of SQLite and Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences) .