# The safest way to store sensitive data on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption, sharedpreferences

Now I use encrypted sharedpreferences.
Sometimes the application can not load or save data and too often crashes randomly during the encryption / decryption process: (
That is why I am looking for a better way to store data.
I need to have immediate access to stored data from multiple load / saves.

Is SQLite Database better choice?
Is SQLite more stable than sharedpreferences?

Comment: Sqllite will more better if data is large. And you can easily perform operation like search,orderby,groupby faster way.

Comment: Note that the SQLite in Android does not by default have any encryption support. So it is up to you to handle the ciphering.

Answer (score 3):

It totally depend on your data, which you want to store.

**SharedPreferences**

```
 1) Small data.
 2) Unstructured.
 3) Like login info, user prefs, etc.
```

> SharedPreferences is a key/value store where you can save a data under
>   certain key. To read the data from the store you have to know the key
>   of the data. This makes reading the data very easy. But as easy as it
>   is to store a small amount of data as difficult it is to store and
>   read large structured data as you need to define key for every single
>   data, furthermore you cannot really search within the data except you
>   have a certain concept for naming the keys.

**SQLite**

```
 1) Large data.
 2) Structured.
 3) Organized.
```

> Large amounts of same structured data should be stored in a SQLite
>   database as databases are designed for this kind of data. As the data
>   is structured and managed by the database, it can be queried to get a
>   sub set of the data which matches certain criteria using a query
>   language like SQL. This makes it possible to search in the data. Of
>   course managing and searching large sets of data influences the
>   performance so reading data from a database can be slower than reading
>   data from SharedPreferences.

Comment: Plagiarism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276936/