# How can I access a non-static method that requires some informations?

Tags: java, android, oop

In my case, I have two classes `MenuActivity, MinhaEscolaActivity`.
There is a method in MenuActivity called `quemSouEu`, it is a non static method.
It also needs some properties defined on MinhaEscolaActivity's constructor method.
If I instanciate a new object of `MinhaEscolaActivity` on `MenuActivity`, these properties will be null, and i'll get `NullPointerException`.

Is there a way to use the method `quemSouEu` from `MenuActivity` class?

Comment: can you show some code of `MenuActivtiy` ?

Comment: Work with fragments, that's not good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt create an activity object by yourself. An activity is a main android component that is meant to be created by the system.

If you have some functions to be shared between activities, you should create another class, and instantiate an object in your activity.

If you also have data to share, you can think about some of the standar ways of sharing data, as you can read [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20904688/2357411)

What are the objects that you are creating on the second class constructor? you could start the activity and get the result, but youshould  only do this if actually you need to show a new view or interact with the user in a diferent way, you shouldnt tell the system to run a new activity just for calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use intents to pass values between activities. You should never create an instance of activity class. Take a look at Raghav Sood's answer in the below post

[Can i Create the object of a activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

Your storage options

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Store the data and retrieve it when you need. Read the docs before choosing one.

You can pass data from `MinhaEscolaActivity` to `MenuActivtiy`using intents and execute the method in `MenuActivity` it self