# Use sharedPreferences or a Database for "one row" of data

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I need persistent storage for my application for a certain activity. I was going to initially use a database table with 5 columns for holding the data I needed, but then I thought that maybe using sharedPreferences may be lighter weight in this case. So my question essentially is, if I am going to use a database for a single entry, should I just use sharedPreferences because I know databases are known for being a bit heavy.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to store the 5 values, then using `SharedPreference` might be preferable. It is also faster than using database. In addition to allow persisting key-value pairs, `SharedPreference` also supports saving `sets` and `ArrayList`. 
See [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences). So storing an array in the `ShraredPrefernce` will suffice.

If you have more structured data, then using database might be better to manage. To know more about when `SharedPreference` would be good to use and when `SQL Lite` database, [Pros and Cons of SQLite and Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences) question is a good read. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sharedPreferences works great for what you are trying to do. It's lightweight and needs the least amount of code to meet your requirement.