# How to use Android SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on an Android project where a user can store some data but is able to delete and change/alter/update the values, I have been searching for a while now for a tutorial, but are not able to find any, so I was wondering, Is it possible to use `SharedPreferences` for that?

Comment: here is a complete tutorial for you 

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far if data is limited to some values, yes you can use SharedPreferences for that. You can easily update/alter/clear values in SharedPreferences.For usage of Shared preferences, refer these

[Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

But if your data is not limited and have some repititive type of values to be stored.For eg. data of app users, their info and all that, then you should go for local database using SQLite. For SQLite,you should go through [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

For pros and cons of SQLite and SharedPreferences, you should go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences)

Comment: Yes the values are rather small and there is no that many, do you have a link or some information on how to do it? The idea is when the values are saved, in the same layout 2 buttons will be added, one to delete and the other to update the values

Answer (score 2):

While you can always read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and know more about `SharedPreferences`, for a quick start here are few static methods from one of my project which you can use.

```
public static boolean getBooleanPrefs(Context ctx, String key) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getBoolean(key, false);
}

public static void setBooleanPrefs(Context ctx, String key, Boolean value) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}

public static String getStringPrefs(Context ctx, String key) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(key, "");
}

public static void setStringPrefs(Context ctx, String key, String value) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putString(key, value).commit();
}

public static int getIntPrefs(Context ctx, String key) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getInt(key, 0);
}

public static void setIntPrefs(Context ctx, String key, int value) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putInt(key, value).commit();
}

public static void clearPrefs(Context ctx) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().clear().commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shared preference is good way to store values. 
need to declare shared preference and stored value to it like.

```
    SharedPreferences prefrs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
                Editor editor = prefrs.edit();
                editor.putString("key",abc);
                editor.commit();
```

you can easily get that value like below...

```
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());  
                   String name = prefs.getString("key", "default");
```

you can delete that stored value and can use for stored new value like below

```
   SharedPreferences prefrs = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefrs.edit();
                            editor.clear();
                            editor.commit();
                            finish();
```