# Android, How to save persistent data?

Tags: android

I have 3 data structures:

1. A set of strings like {"Jack" , "Jason" , "Joe" , ...}
2. A set of (string, int) like {("Jack" , 10) , ("Jason" , 14) , ("Joe" , 11) , ...}
3. A set of (string, int, int) like {("Jack" , 10 , 5) , ("Jason" , 14 , 0) , ("Joe" , 11 , 20) , ...}

By the way:

- Each string is light (just a username) and unique so all set members are unique.
- I need operations like unions, intersections, subtraction, and comparison on all of them.
- I need operations to be fast enough.
- Members of each set may exceed a few thousands.
- I need all of them to be persistent and saved for other application sessions.

According to above, which way you suggest? SharedPreferences or sqlite or file or what? I don't know which is better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences

Comment: If you want to save just key value pairs, SharedPreferences  can be useful. However, complex data structures will require database(i.e. sqlite).

Comment: Use sharedPreference for user settings, sqlite when you will need to access a lot of data repeatedly, and a file when you just want to store it for the next time your app opens. @KrupalShah for complex data structures i will use a file and serializable interface.

Comment: @Nanoc all I am talking according to OP's question perspective.

Comment: @KrupalShah and i edited my comment to show an alternative way to yours as OP is asking for ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks friends, but i need a detailed answer. I've already searched stackoverflow and also googled it. but no clear answer. for now, I'm going to save all the data in a set then put it in a shared pref as a single key value pair. Is a set containing say 5000 usernames and saved in a shared pref a practical choice?

Comment: @xvxph if you have large data like 5000 usernames, just store them in SQLite, sharedprefs is best suite for storing login status or some small system configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used file system and it works fine. Also to handle concurrent access to files i used a readwritelock which also works well.