# Handling intents

Tags: android, listview

I have a button to add a task .. when I press on it , it takes me to another activity to fill the task details such as (task name, desc, duedate..etc) and when I press on save it must transfer just the task name to the first activity to save it in a list view. I don't have any errors but the (Unfortunately, the application has stopped ) occurs at run time error. please help me !!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button add;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),addtask.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);
            }


        });

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        String task= intent.getStringExtra("task");


        ArrayList<String> mylist=new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        mylist.add(task);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.listview, mylist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }}
```

and my second class (activity2)

```
public class addtask extends Activity {
    Button save;
    EditText tasktxt;
    public static String task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dolist);
        tasktxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tasktxt);
        task= tasktxt.getText().toString();
        save= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(addtask.this,MainActivity.class);// define the intent
                intent.putExtra("task",task); // store the message in "message"
                startActivityForResult(intent,0); // calling the other activity
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the logcat if your app crashes

Comment: And `tasktxt.getText().toString()` should be **inside** the `onClick`, otherwise, you have an empty String

Comment: sorry but I very beginner in android :D another question please,, if I want to save the results in the listview so that if I close the application and open it the results will be the same what should I use ? store them in a db or use shared preferences or what !!?

Comment: SharedPreferences aren't designed to store lists, so I think that answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your **First Activity** can be like this:

```
   Button add;
   ListView lv;
   ArrayList<String> mylist=new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>   
        (MainActivity.this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.listview, mylist); 
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),addtask.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);
           });
    }

    @Override  //to receive result 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    
    data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //Use data intent to get string
                    String task = data.getStringExtra("task");

                    //adding new task
                    mylist.add(task);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the **Second Activity** be like this:

```
    public class addtask extends Activity {
    Button save;
    EditText tasktxt;
    public static String task;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dolist);
        tasktxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tasktxt);
        task= tasktxt.getText().toString();
        save= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(addtask.this,MainActivity.class);
                //define the intent
                intent.putExtra("task",task); 

                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); 
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

In the Frist Activity you must override the **onActivityResult** function as   this function is called by the android system when you return data from second activity to the first one .

In the Second Activity you call  **setResult** function to set result code   that will be checked in the first activity, and call **finish()** to remove this activity from the activity stack and go back to the first one.

**I'm not sure if there is an error in your array adapter instantiation or not.*

Comment: Thank u sooooooooooo much !! that works with me perfectly !

Comment: @NAZXD
You are welcome :) , 
This may be helpful for your future questions
http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Naser ,, sorry bit I very beginner in android  :D another question please,, if I want to save the results in the listview so that if I close the application and open it the results will be the same what should I use ? store them in a db or use shared preferences or what !!?

Comment: Comparison:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences  
Shared preferences tutorial:  
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2015/02/android-shared-preferences-example-and-tutorial.html#.V2Uwqfl97IU

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onActivityResult` in **MainActivity**.

And intead of `startActivityForResult()` use `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);` in **addtask**

Answer (score 0):

In your `addtask` Activity you should do:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("task",task); // store the message in "message"
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Then in your MainActivity you should override `onActivityResult` (you will get the intent from addtask there):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            // You can remove this code from onCreate
            String task= data.getStringExtra("task");

            ArrayList<String> mylist=new ArrayList<String>();
            ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            mylist.add(task);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.listview, mylist);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```