# Sqlite or sharedpreference is suitable for my application

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-sharedpreferences

I have an android app with user login i need to store the login details in my app.
My app also has some user history of certain request made by him/her.
My app is a software service app so user details must be stored in app which is fetched from the database

Is  Sqlite or sharedpreference suitable for my application?

Comment: "which is fetched from the database"... Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: A Google search on the subject will show you wonders.

Answer (score 2):

Depends, If you only want to save sessions of user use SharedPrefrence or else if the data is more you can use sqlite

```
   /**
     * method to set the login status for the application
     *
     * @param context
     * @param status
     */
    public static void setLoginStatus(Context context, int status) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY_LOGIN_STATUS, status);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

> NOTE :
>
> About that its totally on your choice what you use to save the current
>   state of user , i will prefer using shared preferences. And for signup
>   and sign in use SQLite database. Shared preferences are commonly used
>   to perform light operations. You can search through data in SQLite as
>   you may have many users.
>
> So use SQLite to register and login and then use shared preferences to
>   save tha current state of user.

Comment: I have just username and password to be saved at the same time a few user details which includes request type request details date etc

Comment: If the user data is more than use sqlite

Comment: I told you If you just want to manage `Sessions` use SharedPrefs OR use sqlite

Comment: You can use both. Session in SharedPreferences. Whatever else in database

Comment: @RautDarpan I can't understand whats ment by more than means what's the normal use of both databae

Comment: @arun There shouldn't be a reason to save a password in your app

Comment: If the data is more complex for `eg: username, place, date etc etc.` then use data base for this and save your `Session` details in `SharedPrefs` look at eg above

Comment: @arunmohan sessions in sense `isUserLoggedIn` or `LoggedOut` `AuthKey`

Comment: @arunmohan see I have updated my answer now you can get what i want to say

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is always a better option to store the data there you can manage in proper format and you can encrypt as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you should use sharedPreferences for saving the login details and i suppose whatever request you are storing, contains more data, so save your requests in SQLite.

Comment: the go for SQLite in case of storing requests

Comment: If am using does it need sharedpreference to store shared preference

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good details about theme :

[Pros and Cons of SQLite and Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences)

> SQLite
>
> Large amounts of same structured data should be stored in a SQLite
>   database as databases are designed for this kind of data. As the data
>   is structured and managed by the database, it can be queried to get a
>   sub set of the data which matches certain criteria using a query
>   language like SQL. This makes it possible to search in the data. Of
>   course managing and searching large sets of data influences the
>   performance so reading data from a database can be slower than reading
>   data from SharedPreferences.
>
> SharedPreferences
>
> SharedPreferences is a key/value store where you can save a data under
>   certain key. To read the data from the store you have to know the key
>   of the data. This makes reading the data very easy. But as easy as it
>   is to store a small amount of data as difficult it is to store and
>   read large structured data as you need to define key for every single
>   data, furthermore you cannot really search within the data except you
>   have a certain concept for naming the keys.

According to the Size or Format of your data you can choose one, for login information I suggest using SharedPreferences

Comment: @RautDarpan I have added the link and the text in the quotations