# Creating Android Cart

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

I am trying to create a cart using android for my e-commerce app. I have thought of using shared preferences but I can also use Sqlite database. I need help on the best method out of the two (shared preferences and sqlite database ) that I should use.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details about the data you would like to store.

Please, refer to the [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences) about SQLite / Shared Preferences comparison on stackoverflow.

Generally: large amount of data -> SQLite, key/value pairs -> shared preferences.

Comment: Thanks... The link you provided has answered my question