# Best way to store data in android after fetching from server

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-sqlite

Hello to everyone I am developing a simple quiz app in which questions and options are coming from server side in json format so i want store that data in phone for using it for exam
what are possible ways to do it. should i use shared preferences or sqlite database or there is any other method or i just store data into array and show it as per my UI (Does it will create more load on server ?). I am getting data from azure storage
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the data is small you can use Shared Prefs but if the data is huge something that needs to stored in a structured manner then you can go for SQLite. And as you said you are building a quiz app then Shared Prefs is enough I reckon.

Comment: Refer this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276358/pros-and-cons-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences

Comment: Depends how you use the data. If are using directly the json, I would suggest you to save you data as json file on internal file. Pro : you don't have to create 2 read/write adapter from what you receive to where you save it and to where you use it. Less work, only 1 read/write adapter. Con : I can't see any :)